# Is DES cryptography available in .NET Standard?

Tags: c#, .net-standard

I'm trying to use DES cryptography in a .NET Standard project (I know it's old and awful, but things out there still use it!) but I cannot find it in the framework for the life of me. All of the crypto classes in .NET Standard appear to reside in the assembly `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms` and browsing the source I can see a DES implementation: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/src/System/Security/Cryptography/DES.cs

My VS2017 IDE refuses to accept that the `DES` class exists in any version of .NET Standard, reporting that:

> The name 'DES' does not exist in the current context

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps it is time to fix "things out there still use it". Isn't that is what a professional in any other field would do? Are we only "Code Monkeys!". Please sir, may I have some more DES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's being added in standard 2.0, [here is a link to the diff between 1.6 and 2.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/standard/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.0_diff.md).  I'm assuming that you're looking for

```
public abstract class DES
```

Additional good news is that it got released I believe, so if you target 2.0 I think you should be good.

Comment: Just in the nick of time too - .NET Standard 2.0 was officially released yesterday.